# reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com/messages/user' failed:

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I facing a problem I have a chat app in Django, and this app worked with me in the development environment put after I deployed it to production id didn't work and shows this messages in the console

```
CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: null, type: "error", target: div, currentTarget: div, …}
```

reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com/messages/user' failed:

My javascript websocket

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reconnecting-websocket/1.0.0/reconnecting-websocket.min.js" integrity=""anonymous"></script>

var loc = window.location
var wsStart = 'ws://'
if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)
```

The Nginx configuration

```
   location /ws/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

Comment: Do you run django using Daphne or Guvicorn.. etc?

Comment: the django app are running with gunicorn but the django channels run with dephne

Comment: Ok, can you show us you Daphne logs?